# Using forEach vs for(var key) with an associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I just want to know why `forEach` doesn't work on an associative array:

```
var array =[];
array['W'] = 0;
array['S'] = 1;

// This doesn't work
console.log(array);
array.forEach(function(item){
console.log(item);
});

// This does
for(var key in array){
console.log(array[key]);
}
```

Comment: You are using an array like an object. Arrays are objects, but they're not used like that. `var array = [];` should be `var object = {};`, then it will become clear.

Comment: if i change array to `var array ={};` it'd throw a `not a function` error on the forEach function as it only runs on arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because `array.length` evaluates to `0`. You could use `Object.values(array).forEach` to iterate over the actual values of the array.

Comment: You're right this works:

Object.values(array).forEach(function(item){
console.log('2',item);
});

Comment: @NaguibIhab If you are using `Object.values` then you might as well change `var array = []` to `var object = {}`.

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) is defined by the standard to iterate over index members.

[`for-in`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofheadevaluation-tdznames-expr-iterationkind) enumerates [all object properties](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-enumerate-object-properties).

So in short, the answer to your "why" question is: because the standard says so.